# Expandable overflow not working in internet explorer

Tags: html, css

I have created the following demo:

http://thedrivepartnership.com/overflow.html

The scrolls expand fine in FireFox / Chrome but in IE it just does seem to want to work.

Does anyone come across the problem before.

css

```
body {padding:0px; margin:0px;}

.wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:red;

}

.block1 {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    width:70%;
    height:50%;
    background:green;

}

.block2 {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    width:70%;
    height:50%;
    background:blue;

}
.heading {width:100%; height:50px; background:black;}

.scroll {
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    top:50px;
    bottom:0px;
    zoom:1
}
```

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="block1">
<div class="heading"></div>
<div class="scroll">
<!--content here -->
</div>
</div>


<div class="block2">
<div class="heading"></div>
<div class="scroll">
<!--content here -->
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design works fine in IE, you just need to declare a DOCTYPE in the first line of your document first.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: Also overflow-x/y is not supported in IE8 or lower. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp

Comment: @Luuky19 page works fine for me in IE8 with a proper DOCTYPE.

Comment: @user1177860 a design that simple-but-complex will rarely work in IE6. The `overflow` property itself doesn't work as it should under ie6, it is classified as buggy.

Comment: @user1177860 by the way, you will have better results using a table layout if you feel that supporting IE6 is imperative, its a 10 year old browser as it is.

Comment: Or frames, frames should work well in IE6 and lower. my advice, don't support IE 6 or lower if you don't have to. like Andres llich says its a 10 year old browser, if you can try to convince your client to upgrade to 7 or 8 if possible.